# localhost issue for Ruby on Rails Existing Project, On a new project everything works fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, localhost

Ruby on rails can't connect to localhost after the server starts normally using `rails s` at the console.

This is the situation:

- boots using thin
- Hosts file is fine
- Created a new project and everything works fine with it
- can't connect to localhost on Existing project(xyz) , no errors in log file
- Same project runs fine on my other laptop
- tried for 127.0.0.1 and other ports

This is what I've tried:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin15]
rails -v
Rails 4.2.1

$ telnet localhost 3000
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
--------------------
```

The output from `rails s` is:

```
Booting Thin
Rails 4.2.1 application starting in development on localhost:3000
Run rails server -h for more startup options
Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: what's the output of `netstat -tna | grep 3000`?

Comment: show us the output when you boot your existing project please, it's likely a config issue.

Comment: @Anthony netstat -tna | grep 3000  .. show no process running on 3000

Comment: @Anthony and rails s output is .. rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.2.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server

Comment: Yesterday, someone was trying to connect to localhost on a remote machine.  Localhost **only** works when accessed from the same machine that the server is running on - it essentially means *this machine*.  Please make absolutely certain that you only have one machine involved in this process, and that one machine that both runs the app with `rails s` and tries to connect to `localhost`.

Comment: Yes i am using the same machine ! @MichaelGaskill

Comment: @PalakMehta No offense intended.  Someone yesterday thought that `localhost` was a domain name published by the Rails server.  I just wanted to make certain that we were talking about the same things here.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill haha i understand, I am well versed with localhost concepts ! i dont think there is any issue with localhost or port 3000 or firewall cause other projects work fine on same port with same ruby version ! Only one particular project of mine is unable to ! i have no idea now what to do !